# Rails scaffold black background

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hyperlink, background-color, scaffolding, scaffold

i've use scaffold to quick setup an rails app but that make a black background on link in the page and in the navbar. Like this : ( my mouse is over 'New city' )

[image: black background scaffold]

That make that also on show, edit, destroy or in the navbar.
I thought it was because of Bootstrap but even without that do that.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time you generate a scaffold it also creates scaffold.css file. Delete it to use your own styling.